What happens if a low-pass filter and a high-pass filter are interchanged in a band-pass filter?

what happens in this circuit if I interchange the highpass filter and lowpass filter how does it affects the gain and phase shift

Remember what I said in an answer to your previous question: The good thing is that you have tried to make the two sections of filter not interact with each other by using impedances that are 100 times bigger for the second stage compared to the first stage.

@Andyaka After runnig a simulation and increasing freq a little bit  the output voltage stabilized in example for 2kHz I get  9.4 mili volts peak  and for 55khz I  get 9.8 mili volts

If you break apart these two sections then you have two independent 1st order filters. And if you mathematically combine them without taking into account loading, then swapping them around doesn't change anything.
For example, your left section is \$\frac{s}{s+\omega_{_0}}\$, where \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R_1\, C_1}\$, and your right section is \$\frac{\omega_{_1}}{s+\omega_{_1}}\$, where \$\omega_{_1}=\frac1{R_2\, C_2}\$. You can just multiply those to get \$\frac{s}{s+\omega_{_0}}\cdot\frac{\omega_{_1}}{s+\omega_{_1}}\$ for the total transfer function, if one isn't loading down the other one. And since multiplication is commutative, it doesn't matter which one goes first.
However, one does load down the other.
In either combination you have a combined 2nd order filter with three important parameters: gain \$A\$, frequency \$\omega\$, and damping factor \$\zeta\$ (or quality factor where \$Q=\frac1{2\,\zeta}\$.) Changing the order modifies \$A\$ and \$\zeta\$.
But it does not alter \$\omega=\frac1{\sqrt{R_1\,R_2\,C_1\,C_2}}\$, which is the same for both cases.
As shown above, you have \$A=\frac1{1+\frac{C_2}{C_1}\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\$. Flipped sections provide \$A=\frac1{1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\left(1+\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)}\$.
For both cases, as shown above or sections flipped, \$\zeta=\frac1{A}\cdot\frac12\cdot R_1\,C_1\cdot\omega\$. But since \$A\$ is likely different between the two cases then so is \$\zeta\$ also likely to be different, now.
The above discussion doesn't assume that \$\omega_{_0}=\omega_{_1}\$, so they can be different and the above math still applies.
But a further simplification comes if you do assume \$\omega_{_0}=\omega_{_1}\$. Then you know that \$R_1\,C_1=R_2\,C_2\$.
Then as shown above you have \$A=\frac1{2+\frac{C_2}{C_1}}\$. And with the sections flipped you have \$A=\frac1{2+\frac{R_2}{R_1}}\$. So, as in the case shown above, \$C_2\ll C_1\$ then \$A\approx \frac12\$. And when the sections are flipped, if it is also the case that \$R_2\ll R_1\$ then also \$A\approx \frac12\$. (With your values above, the flipped case would fail the \$R_2\ll R_1\$ test, though.)
That captures the idea where the 2nd section doesn't load down the first section. \$A\$ will be about the same value in both cases when their associated tests succeed, and then \$\zeta\$, which depends on \$A\$ will also be about the same.
There's two remaining ideas, I suppose. One is the input impedance of the total filter. The other is the output impedance of the total filter. And these matter with respect to a non-ideal source and a non-ideal load.

In ideal case, nothing changes.
But in real life, like what you have there, the output impedance of the first filter and the input impedance of the second filter will affect the results from the ideal case.
If you recalculate the values so that lowpass is first and has very low output impedanve and the highpass is last and has very high impedance, then you should see no change to your current transfer function.
